# Component not updating on key change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

It is my understanding that adding a `key` attribute to a component will allow the component to be reactive when that key changes, but with a `v-navigation-drawer` provided by [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#navigation-drawers) this seems to have no impact.

I've tried even arbitrary changes to a `loggedIn` key such as `+= 1` which would be a change sufficient enough to re-render the component.

The use case here is that I have a global navigation drawer that should show context based on if the user is/isn't logged in.

**Full component**

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    absolute
    right
    dark
    color="primary"
    v-if="$store.state.globalDrawer"
    v-model="$store.state.globalDrawer"
    :key="loggedIn"
  >

  <v-container class="pa-5">
    <v-layout column align-center justify-center>

      <v-avatar class="ma-4" size="60">
        <img v-if="!twitter" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1173674959731867648/6kzApb83_400x400.jpg" />
        <img v-else :src="twitter.profile_image_url" />
      </v-avatar>

      <h2 v-if="!twitter" class="title">StreamBeacon.tv</h2>
      <h2 v-else class="title">{{ twitter.display_name }}</h2>

      <p v-if="!twitter" class="body-2 text-center">Enhance your Going Live experience.</p>
      <p v-else class="body-2 text-center">@{{ twitter.screen_name }}</p>

      <v-chip v-if="twitch.live">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'twitch']" />  
        &nbsp;Live Now
      </v-chip>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>

    <!-- User is authenticated -->
    <v-list dense nav>
      <v-subheader>Account</v-subheader>
      <v-list-item-group 
        color="primary"
        v-if="user"
      >
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(link, i) in accountLinks"
          :key="i"
          :color="activeLinkColor"
          :to="link.target"
          @click="changeDashboardView(link.dashboardComponent)"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon :color="activeLinkColor">
            <v-icon v-text="link.icon"></v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="link.text"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>

    <!-- User is NOT authenticated -->
    <v-list-item-group 
      color="primary"
      v-else
    >
        <v-list-item
          @click="$eventHub.$emit('registration')"
          :color="activeLinkColor"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon color="primary">
            <v-icon>mdi-shield-account</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>Sign In</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>

      <v-subheader>Quick Links</v-subheader>
      <v-list-item-group 
        color="primary"
      >
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(link, i) in quickLinks"
          :key="i"
          :color="activeLinkColor"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon color="primary">
            <v-icon v-text="link.icon"></v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="link.text"></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-group>

    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      user: false,
      twitter: false,
      twitch: false,
      loggedIn: false,
      active: this.$store.state.globalDrawer,
      activeLinkColor: "#fff",
      accountLinks: [
        {
          "icon": "mdi-shield-account",
          "dashboardComponent": null,
          "text": "My Account",
        },
        {
          "icon": "mdi-account-box-multiple",
          "dashboardComponent": "connections",
          "text": "My Connections"
        },
        {
          "icon": "mdi-credit-card",
          "dashboardComponent": "subscription",
          "text": "Subscription",
        },
        {
          "icon": "mdi-bug",
          "dashboardComponent": "support",
          "text": "Support"
        },
        {
          "icon": "mdi-logout",
          "target": "logout",
          "text": "Logout"
        }
      ],
      quickLinks: [
        {
          "icon": "mdi-gift",
          "click": "",
          "text": "Gift a Streamer"
        },
        {
          "icon": "mdi-mail",
          "click": "",
          "text": "Contact Us"
        },
        {
          "icon": "mdi-library-video",
          "click": "",
          "text": "Our Streamers"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    checkIfAuthenticated() {
      if(this.$store.state.authenticatedUser != null) {
        this.user = JSON.parse(this.$store.state.authenticatedUser)
        this.loggedIn = true
        if(this.user.twitter) {
          this.twitter = this.user.twitter
        }
        if(this.user.twitch_channel) {
          this.twitch = this.user.twitch_channel
        }
      }
    },
    changeDashboardView(targetComponent) {
      if(this.$route.name != 'dashboard') {
        this.$router.replace('dashboard')
        .then(() => {
          this.$eventHub.$emit('changeDashboardComponent', targetComponent)
        })
      } else {
        this.$eventHub.$emit('changeDashboardComponent', targetComponent)
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.checkIfAuthenticated()
  },
  watch: {
    $route: function(to, from) {
      this.loggedIn true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Are there circumstances that need to be in order for `key` changes to be effective, or should this be working? I have verified that `loggedIn` does properly change when logging in.

Another theory I had was that because of the `v-if` directive, the component was gone during the key change, however, I debunked this theory already.

Comment: It is Vuex store.

Comment: The proper key is `this.loggedIn`. I had `globalDrawer` as a key as part of troubleshooting. Made an edit.

Comment: Yupp, thanks. That's a symptom of quick editing on SO.

Comment: Why don't you use `getters` in vuex to get `authenticatedUser`?

Comment: Simply knowledge of them. Will make note to look into it.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't know what they are, so lack of use is due to lack of knowledge of them, so I will look into them shortly.

Comment: I see. IMO, if you use `getters`, you will achieve the goal. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: It seems that getters would reduce redundancy, but how would they achieve the goal? `authenticatedUser` is populated, `loggedIn` is populated properly. Both have the expected values, but the component itself isn't reactive. Is there something about `getters` that somehow forces re-render/reactivity?

Comment: I believe I see your point, the authenticatedUser isn't reactive if its not a computed property retrieved by a getter.

Comment: Not quite yet, but it identifies the underlying problem which absolutely does solve the issue, thanks! If you want to write up an answer on using getters with computed properties I'll accept for future readers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue, as Antonio above mentioned, is that I am not using any reactive data for the key & dependencies of the `v-if` directive.

If we look using my code above, after logging in, `user` is still false, which is a value dependency of the context for an authenticated user. On the `mounted()` hook & a route change I look for these & update them, but that's a hacky approach.

**After logging in:**

[image]

The solution was to use a computed property using a Vuex `getter` which will trigger a render on the component.

[image]

This being said, the changes I made to the code above are as follows (subject to change since this goes against current mistakes I need to fix, but keeping it as close to the original to make it easy to read differences).

```
  computed: {
    loggedIn: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.isLoggedIn
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('updateLoggedInState', value)
      }
    },
    user: {
      get() {
        return JSON.parse(this.$store.state.authenticatedUser)
      }
    }
  }
```

**Now after logging in**
[image]

Easy solution, and a good lesson for the day! Thanks, Antonio for the guidance.

Comment: Good explanation!